# how to change a selections options based on another select option selected?

Tags: jquery

here is my html.

```
<select id="type">
<option value="item1">item1</option>
<option value="item2">item2</option>
<option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
<option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
```

here is the jquery i tried but was unsuccessful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if( $("#type").val("item1"))
{
  $("#size").html("<option value='test'>test</option><option value="test2">test2</option>);
}
elseif( $("#type").val("item2"))
{
   $("#size").html("<option value='anothertest1'>anothertest1</option>");
}

});
```

basically what i'm trying to do is if an option is selected in #type then the size select is populated with options associated to it. how can i do this?

thanks

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do => [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#type").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "item1") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item2") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item3") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item0") {
            $("#size").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
    <option value="item0">--Select an Item--</option>
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here is even a cleaner example. In this case, the content is refactored into a JavaScript array. This simplifies the 'change' logic tremendously. Easier to maintain. http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/1/

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i needed. i wasn't too sure to try the == next time ill try thanks.

Comment: greaaaaaat answer !, now i want to try the to change layout.

Comment: Only problem with this example (as is) is that it doesn't set the value for  initial state (of item1).

You need to change it to one value then back to item1 .

Comment: how we can set the selected value of two select box? 
for example i set item3 for selector 1 and item3: test2 for selector 2 
but if i refresh page it not correct.

Comment: I was about to add the same comment as Sir Geek. Is there a way of initializing this so we can have an initial state, including a populated second select element?

Comment: It is never beneficial to repeat an option's text as its `value` attribute.  When the two values are identical, you can safely remove the unneeded HTML markup bloat by omitting the `value` declaration.  Javascript and form submissions will still behave in the same fashion.  This answer is missing its plain English explanation.

Answer (score 14):

you can use **data-tag** in html5 and do this using this code:

```js
<script>
 $('#mainCat').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $("#expertCat option").each(function(item){
   console.log(selected) ;  
   var element =  $(this) ; 
   console.log(element.data("tag")) ; 
   if (element.data("tag") != selected){
    element.hide() ; 
   }else{
    element.show();
   }
  }) ; 
  
  $("#expertCat").val($("#expertCat option:visible:first").val());
  
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mainCat">
   <option value = '1'>navid</option>
   <option value = '2'>javad</option>
   <option value = '3'>mamal</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="expertCat">
   <option  value = '1' data-tag='2'>UI</option>
   <option  value = '2' data-tag='2'>Java Android</option>
   <option  value = '3' data-tag='1'>Web</option>
   <option  value = '3' data-tag='1'>Server</option>
   <option  value = '3' data-tag='3'>Back End</option>
   <option  value = '3' data-tag='3'>.net</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go, and if it's correct I'll give you an upvote, but FYI the code snippet does not work.

Comment: it works but in first run combo box onchange event not raise if you change value of first combo box  this work fine.... this was a sample for changing value by selecting ..... for real world you most refactor this code to work like a charm :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my simple solution using Jquery filters.

```
$('#publisher').on('change', function(e) {
   let selector = $(this).val();
   $("#site > option").hide();
   $("#site > option").filter(function(){return $(this).data('pub') == selector}).show();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pramod4g/9htsLjw4/)

Comment: Note this does not work in IE-- display:none does not hide the option in IE. I used your answer but had to add a few more lines to get it to work in IE  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373558/options-with-displaynone-not-hidden-in-ie

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch case like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#type").change(function () {
     switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'item1':
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
            break;
        case 'item2':
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");
            break;
        case 'item3':
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
            break;
        default:
            $("#size").html("<option value=''>--select one--</option>");
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
    <option value="item0">--Select an Item--</option>
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

as a complementary answer to @Navid_pdp11, which will enable to select the first visible item and work on document load as well.
put the following below your body tag

```
<script>
$('#mainCat').on('change', function() {
    let selected = $(this).val();
    $("#expertCat option").each(function(){
        let element =  $(this) ;
        if (element.data("tag") != selected){
            element.removeClass('visible');
            element.addClass('hidden');
            element.hide() ;
        }else{
            element.removeClass('hidden');
            element.addClass('visible');
            element.show();
        }
    });
    let expertCat = $('#expertCat');
    expertCat.prop('selectedIndex',expertCat.find("option.visible:eq(0)").index());
}).triggerHandler('change');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is setting the value. You want to compare it by doing this

```
if ($("#type").val() == "item1") {
 ...
}
```

daLizard is right though. You want an event handler. document.ready runs only once, when the page DOM is ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quote understand what you are trying to achieve, but you need an event listener. Something like:

```
$('#type').change(function() {
   alert('Value changed to ' + $(this).attr('value'));
});
```

This will give you the value of the selected option tag.

Comment: You probably want to use $(this).val() in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="index">
<select name="in" onchange="myFunction()">
<option>Select One</option>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</select>
<select id="select">
<option>Select One</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var x=document.index.in.value;
if(x=="One"){
document.getElementById('select').innerHTML="<option>A</option><option>Two</option>";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showDiv(prefix, chooser) {
  var selectedOption = (chooser.options[chooser.selectedIndex].value);
  if (selectedOption == "2") {
    var div = document.getElementById(prefix + "2");
    div.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    var div = document.getElementById(prefix + "2");
    div.style.display = 'None';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-label-group">
  <select name="name" id="cboOptions" onchange="showDiv('div',this)" class="form-control">
    <option value="">How can we help you?</option>
    <option value="2">Support</option>
    <option value="1">Feedback</option>
  </select>
  <div id="div2" style="display:none;">
    <select id="type">
      <option value="item0">--Select--</option>
      <option value="item1">Technical</option>
      <option value="item2">Non-Technical</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).