# Feed select options from DB depending on another select options

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a form that has two select fields, one representing the region and one the name of the city/village/etc. I have a database with all these entries in the following form:

```
id (int 11, ai)
region (varchar 50) 
city(varchar 50)
```

I've found a script here on so that lets you select different options but it's made with JS and I have no idea how to adapt it to my needs. I need a database because I have 13.000+ entries and it's not really a good idea to enter them manually in the code. Here is the link to the topic that I've read, it's solution is in one of the comments as well.

[how to change a selections options based on another select option selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480637/how-to-change-a-selections-options-based-on-another-select-option-selected).

Please let me know if I need to edit my post before downrating. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a hugely FAQ. Pls try harder to search first

Comment: You can store regions in table and city in another table. populate select_city with cities and select_region with regions.  When you change the city in select_city send the city id to a php script using ajax, in the php script get the city_id and query the regions table for finding the relevant regions and populate the regions_select

Comment: @mplungjan I searched for a while but I couldn't find a situation that is similar enough to mine and that I understand. I'm a total noob when it comes to JS related things.

Comment: @FirmView Thank you for your answer. However I prefer jcubic's answer because I don't need to change my db structure in any way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use ajax for this, when one select change fetch data from the server to feed other select.

```
<select class="select_one">
<?php /* render first select ?>
</select>
<select class="select_two"></select>
<script>
$(function() {

    $('.select_one').change(function() {
       var select = $('.select_two').empty();
       $.get('script.php', {region: $(this).val()}, function(result) {
           $.each(result, function(i, item) {
               $('<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.name + '</option>').
                   appendTo(select);
           });
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

and you `script.php` should return JSON from db:

```
if (isset($_GET['region'])) {
    $sql = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');
    $region = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql,$_GET['region']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE region = $region";
    $ret = $sql->query($query);
    $result = array();
    while ($row = $ret->fetch_assoc()) {
         $result[] = array(
             'value' => $row['id'],
             'name' => $row['city']
         );
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Ok. In order to use this I guess I need to change the select_one and select_two according to my select names. Also this code should be in the head of the document, inside the script tags, right? If I got it right I'll give it a try!

Comment: Being a total beginner in JS, I can't seem to implement it. Can you provide additional details? Not that your explanation is not clear enough, it's just me. Thanks!

Comment: In some cases, the result won't be added to the options list. Then use `$.each(JSON.parse(result)` instead of just `result`