# Options with display:none not hidden in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, select

I have multiple options in a select. I have sorted the options and disabled and hidden the duplicate options with jquery. The code works well in chrome and firefox but in IE and safari, the options with display:none are still showing up.

Here is the jsfiddle of the code:

```
<select>
  <option value="5797">34</option>
  <option value="5809">37</option>
  ... 
  <option value="5653">71</option>
  <option disabled="" selected="selected" value="53">Eye</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" style="display: none;" value="5441">52</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" style="display: none;" value="5443">52</option>
  ...
  <option disabled="disabled" style="display: none;" value="5431">51</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vUdb/

Comment: Which versions of IE are you having trouble with. I know for a fact that IE8 and earlier have *extremely* limited ability for styling select boxes.

Comment: I am testing it on IE 10.

Comment: IE 11 still has the same behaviour.

Comment: Confirmed this is still an issue in Edge as well

Answer (score 36):

IE doesn't support `style="display:none;"` on `<option>` tags.

Your only option is to remove them - either as part of the creation of the HTML, or via client-side script.

Answer (score 21):

If somebody still faces this issue, here is my solution, it may be helpfull:

```
$('select.some-list option[id=someId]').attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
```

This hides the option in all browsers and disables if can't hide :).
To bring back the option do not forget to enable it:

```
$('select.some-list option[id=someId]').removeAttr('disabled').show();
```

Comment: @Gev, Show a non-jquery solution.

Comment: This works in ie 9 as well. Thanks so much for the solution!

Comment: Does not seem to be working in Edge. [Has been reported](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5457477/) on MS Dev forum, says to be fixed, but I still have the problem.

Comment: This solution cannot hide the option. I really want to hide it completely.

Comment: You should use `.prop()` here not add/remove an attribute

Answer (score 4):

You can use `detach()` and `remove()` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

> **Expanding on Zhangjiang Huang's answer:** Pretty much you cache all the options, detach them from the drop-down, then you reattach the ones you want.

**JQuery:**

```
(function(){
   // Cache List
   var options = $("select option");

   // Clear list
   options.detach();
   // Rebuild list
   options.not(".disabled").appendTo("select");
   // Set Default
   $("select").val("");
})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<select>
   <option value="">---Select One---</option>
   <option value="5797">34</option>
   <option value="5809">37</option>
    ... 
   <option value="5653">71</option>
   <option class="disabled" value="53">Eye</option>
   <option class="disabled"value="5441">52</option>
   <option class="disabled" value="5443">52</option>
   ...
   <option class="disabled" value="5431">51</option>
</select>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqsx3dga/)

Answer (score 1):

Use following Js to hide option tag

```
<select id="selectlist">
      <option value="5797">34</option>
      <option value="5809">37</option>
       <option value="5653">71</option>
      <option  value="53">Eye</option>
      <option  value="5441">52</option>
      <option  value="5443">52</option>
      <option value="5431">51</option>
    </select>


$('#selectlist option[value=53]').hide();
$('#selectlist option[value=52]').hide();
$('#selectlist option[value=5443]').hide();
```

Ref : jsfiddle.net/p8Gmm/7

Or

Ref :

http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/vhKdw/

Comment: I dont need to remove any option. Your JSfiddle removes the option!

Comment: What does your second JSfiddle do with display!!! In that just an option is disabled!

Comment: You have to use like 
$('#selectlist option[value=53]').hide();

Comment: @MJQ, you appear to be waiting for a solution that means that `<option style="display:none">` will work in IE.  **Stop waiting, it doesn't work**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p8Gmm/7/ see my this fiddle with inspecting element of the select

Comment: @ freefaller : he can use js for this, like   
jsfiddle.net/p8Gmm/7, he can get his solution like this.

Comment: @ freefaller: I am not waiting. I am trying my bit to resolve it!

Comment: @freefaller, Is it listed anywhere on modern.ie? Can't seem to find it http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/?filter=f3f0000bf&search=option

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents worth on an "old question", yet still a relevant issue.

Server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   { //load subDropDownList all possible values [with an attribute for filtering] }
}
```

Client-side:

```
var optionList = null;
$(function(){
  if (!optionList)
  {
     optionList = new Array();
     $("[id$='subDropDownList'] option").each(function () {
         optionList.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text(), filterID: $(this).data("filterid") }); 
      });
  } 

  $("[id$='mainDropDownList']").on("change", function (e) {
     var filterID = $(this).val();
     $("[id$='subDropDownList']").html("");

     $.each(optionList, function () {
        if (this.filterID == filterID)
          $("[id$='subDropDownList']").append($("<option></option>").val(this.value).html(this.text).data("filterid", this.filterID));
        });


  });

})
```

The idea here is on client side I load all values into an array, then on change event of the main select I add only the required options. Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The [solution by @Gev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373558/options-with-displaynone-not-hidden-in-ie#28898023) is good, but the options still appear (even though disabled), so the behaviour is inconsistent across browsers.

You could [amend the `option` tag to something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag#918803) which stops it appearing, but then you lose any attributes or HTML5 data tags.

The solution I came up with was to wrap any options you want disabled in a different  tag (in this case a made up one, which does the job and makes it clear what's happening).

Starting with example of options also with optional data tags:

```
<select id="myselections">
  <option data-something="a" value="5797">34</option>
  <option data-something="f" value="5809">37</option>
  <option data-something="j" value="5653">71</option>
</select>
```

To hide the options you don't want:

```
$("#myselections > option").each(function () {
    if(some check) {
        $(this).wrap("<optionhidden></optionhidden>");
    }
});
```

To undo the above on the whole list before hiding different options:

```
$("#myselections > optionhidden").each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here in IE 10, 11, Edge.. 
Options will not disapear like in Firefox, Chrome, ..

*(jQuery-Code)*

Works not:

- $('option').hide();
- $('option').attr('style', 'display: none !important');
- $('option').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

But that works!

```
$('option').unwrap('div').wrap('<div style="display: none;" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var detachedSecondElem,detachedFirstElem="";
var firstDetachedAt, secondDetachedAt;
function changedFirst(){
 var val1=$('#slct').val();
 if(detachedSecondElem!="")
  $( detachedSecondElem ).insertAfter( $("#slct1 option").eq((secondDetachedAt-1)) );

 if(val1!=""){
   secondDetachedAt = $('#slct1 option[value="'+val1+'"]').prevAll().length;
   detachedSecondElem = $('#slct1 option[value="'+val1+'"]').detach();
 }
}
function changedSecond(){
 var val2=$('#slct1').val();
 if(detachedFirstElem!="")
  $( detachedFirstElem).insertAfter( $("#slct option").eq((firstDetachedAt-1)) );

 if(val2!=""){
   firstDetachedAt= $('#slct option[value="'+val2+'"]').prevAll().length;
   detachedFirstElem= $('#slct option[value="'+val2+'"]').detach();
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="slct" onchange="changedFirst();"> 
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="slct1" onchange="changedSecond();"> 
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="disableOption();"/>
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="attachElem();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort by disabled options. 

$("#addselect option").each(function (i, val) {
                if ($(this)[i].disabled) {
                    moveDown("selectId");
                }
                else {
                    moveUp("selectId");
                }
 }

   function moveUp(selectId) {
            var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
            var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
            for (var i = 1; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
                var opt = selectOptions[i];
                if (!opt.disabled) {
                    selectList.removeChild(opt);
                    selectList.insertBefore(opt, selectOptions[i - 1]);
                }
            }
        }

        function moveDown(selectId) {
            var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
            var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
            for (var i = selectOptions.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
                var opt = selectOptions[i];
                if (opt.disabled) {
                    var nextOpt = selectOptions[i + 1];
                    opt = selectList.removeChild(opt);
                    nextOpt = selectList.replaceChild(opt, nextOpt);
                    selectList.insertBefore(nextOpt, opt);
                }
            }
        }
```