# How to hide only one option element using css only

Tags: html, css

```
 <select class="Select-input">
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
   <option value="three">Three</option>
   <option value="four">Four</option>
 </select>
```

I want to hide only value four from the above code.

I tried using {display:none} for value-four but it didn't work.

Also want to add padding between [this elements](http://puu.sh/lXMUP/7d31512467.png) one, two, three and four.

P.S. I want to remove it using CSS only.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that all of our biggest browsers will disagree on how this should be handled. FF and Chrome will accept display:none and deal with it properly, while IE, Edge and Safari will ignore it. After my own search this is what I've found:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css

Answer (score 11):

Attribute selector is the key, although as Musa points out, you can't hide a option in internet explorer.

Article here on hiding option in IE [Options with display:none not hidden in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373558/options-with-displaynone-not-hidden-in-ie)

```css
   .Select-input option[value=four] {display: none;}
```

```html
 <select class="Select-input">
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
   <option value="three">Three</option>
   <option value="four">Four</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: That's not what I meant, you **can't** hide options in IE

Answer (score 4):

I took the part Aaron already answered and added the requested padding:

```css
option {padding: 7px 0px 7px 5px;}

option[value=four] {display: none;}
```

```html
<select class="Select-input">
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
   <option value="three">Three</option>
   <option value="four">Four</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
.Select-input option:nth-child(4){
  display: none;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/94/)**

Comment: Its working here in DEMO but not in actual site.

I think Chrome is not allowing this.

Comment: Chrome cache is stiff and hard to let go! Clear cache completely and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, may help

```
select option:last-child {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.Select-input option:nth-of-type(2) {
    display:none;
}
```

Or you can do this to:

```
.Select-input option:nth-child(1){
   display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <select class="Select-input">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
      <option value="four" style="display:none;">Four</option>
    </select>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**Use inline CSS if you just want to hide just one option using CSS.**

*If you want to display:block; or display:none; dynamically than use javascript.*

**Hopefully my contribution will help you.**