# display:none does not work in IE for option tag

Tags: html, css, user-interface, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

`display:none` is not working in `IE`, can any one please answer to my question?

If it does not work in IE11, is there any alternative solution?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #id1 {
        display:none !important;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <select multiple>
        <option id="id1">1</option>
        <option id="id2">2</option>
        <option id="id3">3</option>
        <option id="id4">4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach is using `disabled="disabled"` for option in IE. 
It's not a perfect solution, but it does another safe way to make option be un-selectable for user

Answer (score 0):

Basically, IE doesn't support `style="display:none;"` or `Option` tag or other relevant used as in mozilla, chrome or safari. Therefore, you can use jquery to hide the Option.
in related to the question, you have identical question as in: [Options with display:none not hidden in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373558/options-with-displaynone-not-hidden-in-ie)

If you wish, **single dropdown menu** will solve your problem.

Comment: It's working for other tags, except <option> tag, is there any solution for <option> tag.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#id1{
display:none !important;
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<select multiple>
<option id="id1">1</option>
<option id="id2">2</option>
<option id="id3">3</option>
<option id="id4">4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `display: none;` to `<option>`, it only works in Firefox.
Check this: [How to hide a <option> in a <select> menu with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234830/how-to-hide-a-option-in-a-select-menu-with-css)