# AngularJS Hide first empty option in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I am trying to get rid of an empty option at the top of my select. This solution works in Chrome but not in IE as IE doesn't support `display:none` on options.

```
<option value="" style="display:none"></option>
```

What would be the best way to hide it? I'm using AngularJS framework and tried plenty of solutions like ng-if but none of them work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373558/options-with-displaynone-not-hidden-in-ie

Comment: Your solution will not work in IE. If you are using AngularJS anyway, what about just editing the DOM and removing the <option>? If you need the <option> in another context, you can dynamically add/remove it.

Comment: I have seen that topic and I can't see how any of the answers is actually a reasonable choice. PS: I am not using jQuery.

Comment: If you have a reference to the select element, then `select.removeChild(select.options[0])` will do the job.

Comment: If you're using angularJS then you can set model to filtered copy of your array (I assume you are using ng-repeat)

Comment: @barbsan, I am using ng-options and my array isn't populated with an empty option. It is done by something in the background. Probably select's functionality.

Comment: Could you show more code? Propably you can use filter to filter out specific values (like `ng-options="option in options | filter: functionToRemoveSomeOptions "`). Note: functionToRemoveSomeOptions returns boolean

Comment: Instead of fix in the wrong way, you shouldn't populate the empty options in the select element...

Comment: I am not populating the empty options... I assume it's angular that's doing that somehow. I've read it adds empty option when ng-model is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've eventually came up with this solution. Isn't the prettiest but is a spot on fix for me

```
<option ng-if="false" value=""></option>
```