# Filter information between selection lists

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a website where people can vote. In the registration part, people can select their city and state, but what I really want to do is to filter cities depending on their state, using information from the SQLite database. Here's how I called the selection list in my program:

```
<%= f.label "Ciudad:" %>
<%= f.select :ciudade_id, grouped_options_for_select(Departamento.order(:nombre).map{ |group| [group.nombre, group.ciudades.map{ |ciudade| [ciudade.nombre, ciudade.id] } ] }), { prompt: true}, {:onchange => 'populate(this.id, 'puesto_id')'}, required: true, class: ' order_form ciudades_search'%>
```

This is how the project is looking:

**State selection.**

[image]

**City selection:**

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: why is this tagged as javascript?

Comment: I've done some investigation, if I want to make changes depending of what I'm choosing for, it's necessary some javascript, maybe jquery. As I said, I'm new here and programing in Rails and I need some help. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change a selections options based on another select option selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480637/how-to-change-a-selections-options-based-on-another-select-option-selected)

Comment: Well, I'm selecting items from my database, not from a HTML  <option>. Also, what I want to know is if it is possible to filter the information in real time, and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the states/cities information you have in your Rails database via AJAX then you need to create a route and controller which serves up that info.

However SQLite is not really going to cut it - it's not built for large production databases and does not have any good features for searching like `ILIKE`. I would recommend Postgres.

```
resources :states, only: [:show, :index]
```

---

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
end
```

---

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /states(.json)
  def index
    @states = State.all
    @states = State.where("name ILIKE ?", params[:search]) if params[:search]
    render json: @states
  end
  # GET /states/:id(.json)
  def show
    @state = State.includes(:cities).find(params[:id])
    render json: @state, include: :cities
  end
end
```

You can then use this together with something like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) or roll your own solution.

But if you are creating a global application you might want to use service like http://www.geonames.org/ as keeping an up to date global database would be insane.

Comment: No, as I already wrote SQLite does not have `LIKE` or `ILIKE` so there is no good way to do text search. SQLite is meant for quick development or to be embedded on devices.