# keep selected option displayed when options based on another select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML < form > with two independent < select >. The < option > available in the second < select > is based on the < option > chosen in the first < select >. This works fine using the suggestion from [mcravens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480637/how-to-change-a-selections-options-based-on-another-select-option-selected) and further detailed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/1/).

Although the first < select > value is retained when pressing the < submit > button, the selected value in the second < select > is always reset to "-- select one --" .  I would like the second selected value to remain displayed and unchanged until manually changed OR the first < option > is changed (which changes the second options available).

I have been able to capture the value of the second selected value by adding a name to the select:
(HTML)

```
<select name="CSsize" id="size">
   <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
```

and then using a $_POST to collect the selected value:
(PHP)

```
if(isset($_POST["CSsize"]) && !empty($_POST["CSsize"])) { 
    $CSsize = $_POST["CSsize"];} else { $CSsize="0";}
```

This means that I can capture the value of the second < select > once submitted and use it in the remaining code. There is no issue there, my question is purely how to keep the chosen value displayed in the second < select > on the page.

I have tried revising the second < select > with PHP echo, etc., such as:

```
<option <?php if ($CSsize != "0" ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value=""></option>
```

and also tried revising the .js with if statements, such as:

```
if ($("#size").val() !== "Select...") {
```

Nothing seems to work and the second < select > is stubornly reset each time.

I'd love some assistance in showing me where I am going wrong?! Thanks!

Comment: `if ($CSsize != "0" )`, selected option will be applied to all the options isn't it ? Don;t you think it should be applied for single option ? You need to consider value of the option as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I can capture the value of the second < select > once submitted and use it in the remaining code*

If I understand this correctly, you can generate the `option`'s `selected` property using captured results in the following `script` area

```
"<option>item1...</option><option <?php echo .... 'selected'; ?> >item1...</option>"...
```

*If `.js file` manipulation using `php` is not an option, using `data` attribute in the `select` element and retrieving it via `.data()` can work.*

Then calling the `$("#type").change()` at the end of `.ready()` will executes the handler and construct the 2nd select box as usual.

```
 $("#type").change();
```

[See Demo](http://codepen.io/CreativeCreate/pen/pyboGM?editors=1010)

Comment: Excellent. With a little modification this works perfectly. In case this helps someone in the future, the final 'full' code is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading the page and have got the value of second select then just call the following code

```
var val = $('#type').val();
$("#size").html(options[val]);
```

[Check the fiddle link for you solution](http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/966/)

Hope this helps