# Query database in select onchange

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, wordpress, select

I'd like to know how can I approach this better and what are my options. I cannot use AJAX requests for this.

I have a dropdown select populated through a `SELECT` query from the Database. The dropdown displays the user's display_name as the **label** and their **IDs** as the value. So:

`$('select').val()` retrieves an ID.

My problem is I'd like to display the selected user's username (another column from the same database table) in the onchange event of the Dropdown select.

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

**EDIT:**

I'm usiing Advanced Custom Functions for Wordpress, so this is how I'm retrieving my select and populating it:

```
function acf_load_color_field_choices( $field ) {
    $field['choices'] = array();

    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $field['choices'][$row[ID]] = $row[display_name];
    }

    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=select_name', 'acf_load_color_field_choices');
```

Any idea if there's a way to add a data- attribute to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480637/how-to-change-a-selections-options-based-on-another-select-option-selected

Comment: did you want get the select box text instead of id ?

Comment: You can add "data-" attribute to items of select. For ex: data-username. Than you can retrieve it.

Comment: The select holds the display_name and the IDs, I want the username which isn't part of the select... Not sure if I can't add that data-username attribute to the select. I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was faster than figuring out if the plugin provided the `data-name` attribute, I managed to resolve my problem by changing my logic around.

Instead of passing the ID as a value, I've passed the username as a value. Then on the receiving end, I did a query to get the ID based on the username (since username is unique).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the best approach as you can't use `AJAX` would be

- You can actually fetch the username along with the query you use to populate the select.
- Create an attribute in the `option` tags and fill the names from the query against the id's in the tags like `<option data-name='Name' value='' ></option>`
- Fetch this attribute on change and your problem would be met

Comment: I've edited the question, please let me know if I can still apply your solution. Thanks