# How to change a select list option when other select list changed using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the content of a select list if i choose something special in another select list, for example if i choose "Even" on select list 1 i would like to be able to choose between 2 ; 4 ; 6 ; 8 on Select list 2, same for "Odd" (1 ; 3 ; 5 
; 7 ; 9).

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480637/how-to-change-a-selections-options-based-on-another-select-option-selected

Comment: Haven't learned jquery for now, is it totaly nescessary?

Comment: well you can learn jQuery. it will help you reduce your code compare to javascript

Comment: Ok, so, is there any possibility external to jquery ?

Comment: Most threads on SO are from jquery.

Comment: Most threads on SO are from jquery.

Comment: How to use Jquery ? place it in .js like javascript ?

Comment: include jquery cdn and then you can use jquery with <script></script> same as js

Comment: check this:- https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_lib_google