# Add dependent select box using html & Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the dropdown in the frontend form for RMA. I want to add the dependent dropdown for more specifically describe the reason.

Parent Dropdown:

```
<select type="select" name="reason_id" id="reason_id" title="Choose Reason" class="validate-select required-entry">
    <option value="">Please select reason</option>
    <option value="1">Defective</option>
    <option value="2">Wrong Item</option>
    <option value="3">Damaged in Transit</option>
    <option value="5">Return</option>
    <option value="4">Other</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to add the second dropdown on change parent dropdown option.

for example: I am choosing "Defective" option from the parent dropdown then the below option will be dispalyed:

```
<select type="select" name="reason_id" id="reason_id" title="Choose Reason" class="validate-select required-entry">
    <option value="">Please select reason</option>
    <option value="1">Did not Fit</option>
    <option value="2">Stopped working after a certain time</option>
    <option value="3">Other</option>
</select>
```

for example: When I choosing "Wrong Item" from the parent dropdown then the below option will be dispalyed:

```
<select type="select" name="reason_id" id="reason_id" title="Choose Reason" class="validate-select required-entry">
    <option value="">Please select reason</option>
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

All items will be fixed.

How can add using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change a selections options based on another select option selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480637/how-to-change-a-selections-options-based-on-another-select-option-selected)

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the expected behavior.
In the code i rested the form with the content based on the value selected in the parent drop down.

If user selects the *Defective*  option then the reason for the defective will be displayed.

```
 $("#reason_id").on("change", function(){
        var selected = $(this).val();
        if($(this).val()==1){
          $("#reason_form").html('');
          $("#reason_form").html(defectiveHTML);
        }
      });
```

if the selected value one i will change the content of the form with the child dropdown.

Please find the sample code.
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqLmyL)

Answer (score 1):

You are required to add parent div for each select box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   Event.observe(document, 'dom:loaded', function(event) {
        if ($('reason_id').value === '1') {
            $('defective_dependent').show();
        }
        if ($('reason_id').value === '2') {
            $('wrong_item_dependent').show();
        }
        if ($('reason_id').value === '5') {
            $('return_dependent').show();
        }
        ............
        ............
        ............
        Event.observe($('reason_id'), 'change', function(event){
            if ($('reason_id').value === '1') {
                    $('defective_dependent').show();
                }else {
                    $('defective_dependent').hide();
                }
                if ($('reason_id').value === '2') {
                    $('wrong_item_dependent').show();
                }else {
                    $('wrong_item_dependent').hide();
                }
                if ($('reason_id').value === '5') {
                    $('return_dependent').show();
                }else {
                    $('return_dependent').hide();
                }
                .....................
                .....................
                .....................
            });
        });
</script>
```